# Interface design of a java project "File Finder"

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

I am working on a project **File Finder** in java.
I have to design the ***interface*** from where user interacts and access database.
I want to know what are the basic items of applet i need to use for it.

I have added two combo boxes and labes one for file extension and other for file name and a submit button.Are there any other items neccessary for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies if I'm wrong here, but should this have the homework tag?

Answer (score -1):

For usability you should have only one text field where the user can perform the queries like google has. the text field should perform the search when pressing the enter key or add an additional button named "search."